# En que casos utilizar servidor de aplicaciones en Java

Tags: java, servidor, jboss

¿Qué funcionalidad ofrece un servidor de aplicaciones Java como JBoss frente a un servidor Web como Tomcat?

¿Qué debo tener en cuenta a la hora de elegir una opción sobre la otra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss es un servidor de aplicaciones que también puede ser usado como servidor Web.

Tomcat o Jetty son contenedores de Servlets, y pueden manejar tanto servlets como JSPs, pero no otras tecnologías JEE de manera directa, sin añadir el soporte en forma de librerías adicionales (usando Spring, por ejemplo).

JBoss, al ser un servidor de aplicaciones, sí soporta estas tecnologías. Según la versión de JBoss soportará una versión diferente de JEE.

Dicho esto, toda decisión acerca de qué usar debe partir de tus necesidades. Si con un servidor como Tomcat te arreglas, ya sea por estar desarrollando una aplicación simple con servlets o JSPs, o por utilizar un framework como Spring que te proporcione funcionalidad similar a la que te daría un servidor de aplicaciones, ya te sería suficiente. En caso contrario, necesitarás un servidor como JBoss.

Comment: Entiendo, básicamente entonces, si solamente utilizo servlet, jsp, y tecnologías propias de la web basta y sobra con tener un servidor tomcat. JPA es crear conexiones persistentes a la BD desde clases Java verdad? cosa que se puede obviar haciendo clases de acceso a la base, tipo dto y dao, es así? En cuanto a EJB, cuál sería su propósito? Disculpame la molestia, pasa que estoy más metido en lo que es Java Swing y JDBC básico y me gustaría entender estas otras tecnologías

Comment: EJB te proporciona transaccionalidad, control de concurrencia, eventos, seguridad, funcionalidad de estado, etc.

Comment: Como indicas, se puede usar JDBC directamente y olvidar JPA.

Answer (score 2):

La división no es entre "servidores Web" o "servidores Java"; todos los servidores que nombras son "Web" y "Java".

La diferencia está en que hay una definición de lo que es el Java Enterprise Edition, que es un estándar que define una serie de servicios que los *containers* ("servidores") ofrecen a las aplicaciones.

Para ser un *container* o servidor JEE el servidor debe proporcionar todos los servicios definidos como obligatorios para la especificaciones (ejemplo Glassfish, JBoss, etc.).

Otros servidores no proporcionan estos servicios, o sólo una parte (por ejemplo Tomcat).

Sobre cuál usar, depende de tus necesidades y, dentro de ellas, de tus gustos. Si sólo usas la parte EE de Web, normalmente  un Tomcat es suficiente, pero también van bien Glassfish y JBoss si estás más familiarizado con ellos. Si empiezas a usar funcionalidades JEE, es mejor usar un container JEE directamente.